# Creating Self Learning Sentiment Dictionary

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, sentiment-analysis

I am planning to **build a self-learning dictionary** of sentiment word with their sentiment label.

I am able to identify the sentiment words by using POS tags but not able to label those words as positive, negative or neutral.

For example: "The food was not good" is the sentence, and I have extracted "not good" from the sentence as sentiment word by using the POS tag. Now I want to label this as negative and add it to my new dictionary for future use.

my preference to do this project/task is by not using any pre-defined dictionary/word bank/any pre-defined sentiment analysis package.

**I am seeking your views to know the way to label it without using any pre-defined dictionary or with pre-defined dictionary.**

Currently, I have explored Word embedding, Skip through n-gram model for this. I have also used a pre-defined dictionary to train the model by using some supervised learning model like Xgboost, KNN,  Naive Bayes classifier. I have used some unsupervised model like k-mean to predict the label by using the words. 
Still not able to get the results.

If You know any other way or some input to apply with any of above-used models to label word as positive, negative or neutral then please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Okay let me help you with basic suggestion, due  i also have done something like this in college. First you must have at least several words (or phrase). More words you have, more vary the result you'll get. To help build the feature, your word must be cleaned up from Caps and reading quotation, then tokenized it by delimiter and has been tagged with the kind of word (NN, PRO,etc).

For tagging the word or phrase, in case if the word or phrase has positive or negative or something else, you must define it by yourself. Python NLTK is the best library for tag English words based from its kind of word, but you must define for the sentiment. So you can store your features for your data source in kind of array like this:

```
    {"anarchy","VB","+"} 
where the format is
 {<word>,
<type_of_word>,
<sentiment_class>}
```

In case you have another word, just do a classification method with your training dataset and store the result into your data set. But this kind of technique will fail if the classified words has high inaccuracy.

But my notice is, be careful with a word that have several kind of sentiment (looks like it positive but actually has negative sentiment based from its sentence context, or reverse). So the best advice is,make your model to tag the sentiment of the word in the sentence not as when the word stand by itself , but as it's position in the sentence. This is the example of the feature for phrase like "The anarchy peoples" (note that after cleaning, all words are converted into small-caps)

```
     {"anarchy","VB","the","PP","peoples","NNP","0,001","+"}

 where the format is 

{<word>,
<type_of_word>,
<word_before your word>,
<type_of_word_before>,
<word_after>,
<kind_of_word_after>,
<probability_of_word_presence>,
<sentiment_class>}
```

I suggest you to read some [related researches](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=sentiment%20analysis) about sentiment analysis before do this.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I follow this approach then can you please tell me about the accuracy as you said you have worked on this. It will be helpful for me to start work on this. And one more thing I would like to know, whether I should clean the text or not. Because words will get different POS tag after cleaning.

Comment: There're some effect if you clean the words or just keep as it was. The accuracy you must to analyze is about the word sentiment are right as expected. but to make sure it, just read some research about sentiment analysis and search for accuracy measurement from the classification result